# Programmatically turn on "aws transfer for SFTP"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

How can I programmatically turn-on or off the "AWS Transfer for SFTP". I just need to have the end-point opened only a few hours a day?

Answer (score 0):

The API for AWS Transfer can be found at: [API Reference - AWS Transfer for SFTP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/API_Reference.html)

There are also SDKs for specific languages, such as: [Transfer — Boto 3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/transfer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jus tin case you need links to specific API to start / stop server

Start Server: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/API_StartServer.html

Stop Server: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/API_StopServer.html